# Google Play Games: "Out of box error detected; the user must reauthenticate through the UIflow."

Tags: android, c++, authentication, google-play-games

When I sign in to Google Play Games on my Android device from my game, I get:

**Out of box error detected; the user must reauthenticate through the UIflow.**

This app used to work well with google play. But my latest build has this issue.

I use the C++ version of Google Play Games integration: [gpg-cpp-sdk_3.1](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/sdks)

I do see a notification pop up saying "Hey there, gamertag" and "Level 16". So it does briefly log in, but then is immediately logged out again.

```
V  Play Games callback indicates connection.
I  Successfully connected to Google Play.
V  WelcomeBack Notification UI should be displayed by GMSCore.
V  ApplicationMetadataCache is not being seeded; this is normal on non-iOS platforms.
I  Sign in finished with a result VALID
I  OnAuthActionFinished
I  You are logged in!
V  PlayerLevelCache is not being seeded; this is normal on Android.
V  Automatically seeded event cache.
E  Out of box error detected; the user must reauthenticate through the UIflow.
```

This is a debug build of my game, but I'm pretty sure GPG works with both debug and release builds. I have keys for both, uploaded to the google play console.

No significant source code changes from my side. Just a rebuild of the game, with a much newer Android Studio.

UPDATE: This issue does not happen for an emulated device, but does happen for a Xiaomi Mi A3 device.

Answer (score 0):

This error went away, when I cleared caches. On Android 11, this is done via:

- Open **Settings** App:
- Tap **Storage**
- **Other apps**
- For each of: Google Play services, Google Play Games, and the misbehaving game:
- **Clear Cache**
- **Clear Data**

Android always has been, and always will be, one big heap of misery.